# Comparing image on how much degrees tilted

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have an problem as seen below the one on top is the original image the one on the bottom is titlted to the left 90 degrees. Is there a way to calculate the change in angle. I have tried Hough's Transform, I can detect the location, however I cannot detect the angel that is changed. Is there an alternative to detect the degreeschanged.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do I fix it?? I never noticed this.

Comment: You need to choose best answer by ticking it.

Comment: ...assuming it actually solves your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this before using a Symmetric Phase-Only Matched Filter.  It was actually for fingerprint recognition, allowing rotation and scaling.  Unfortunately, it's pretty complicated.  You need to be comfortable with how to compute an FFT and with similar-level math.  I did not do it in C#, but in MATLAB (and in synthesizable Verilog, but that's another story altogether).  I would recommend using MATLAB or a similar math package first to be sure you have the algorithm right.

Hopefully, though, someone has already implemented this algorithm in a .NET image processing library somewhere.

The paper I used was the following.  It is more math-based than algorithmic, so it will take some work to convert it to code:

> Qin-Sheng Chen; Defrise, M.; Deconinck, F.
>   ["Symmetric phase-only
>   matched filtering of Fourier-Mellin
>   transforms for image registration and
>   recognition,"](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=387491&isnumber=8785)
>   Pattern Analysis and
>   Machine Intelligence, IEEE
>   Transactions on , vol.16, no.12,
>   pp.1156-1168, Dec 1994
>
> **Abstract**: Presents a new method to
>   match a 2D image to a translated,
>   rotated and scaled reference image.
>   The approach consists of two steps:
>   the calculation of a Fourier-Mellin
>   invariant (FMI) descriptor for each
>   image to be matched, and the matching
>   of the FMI descriptors. The FMI
>   descriptor is translation invariant,
>   and represents rotation and scaling as
>   translations in parameter space. The
>   matching of the FMI descriptors is
>   achieved using symmetric phase-only
>   matched filtering (SPOMF). The
>   performance of the FMI-SPOMF algorithm
>   is the same or similar to that of
>   phase-only matched filtering when
>   dealing with image translations. The
>   significant advantage of the new
>   technique is its capability to match
>   rotated and scaled images accurately
>   and efficiently. The innovation is the
>   application of SPOMF to the FMI
>   descriptors, which guarantees high
>   discriminating power and excellent
>   robustness in the presence of noise.
>   This paper describes the principle of
>   the new method and its discrete
>   implementation for either image
>   detection problems or image
>   registration problems. Practical
>   results are presented for various
>   applications in medical imaging,
>   remote sensing, fingerprint
>   recognition and multiobject
>   identification

Comment: I am willing to try it out with Matlab, however I am new to it. Do you mind to provide any docuement or libraries to help me. Thanks..

Comment: @user288231 - I've actually lost all of my documents/code for this.  It was a few years ago in school and I never really saw it as that important.  I'm lucky I remembered enough to find the paper... Sorry!  The IEEE paper I linked to is decent (you need to be a member though).

Answer (score 0):

You can also rotate second image in a loop by constant angle and calculate [RMSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square_deviation) between two images in each iteration. Matching angle will be where RMSE is minimum.

Here is [powershell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) script which implements this idea with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php):

```
# convert images to equal sizes for pixel by pixel comparision
convert.exe p1.png -resize 73x73! p1.png
convert.exe p2.png -resize 73x73! p2.png

# initialize variables
$min_rmse = 1.0
$degrees_rotated = -1.0

# rotate second image by 10 degrees in each iteration
# and after that measure RMSE between first image and second rotated image
for ($i=0; $i -le 350; $i+=10) {
    convert.exe p2.png -rotate $i tmp.png
    convert.exe tmp.png -resize 73x73! tmp.png
    $rmse = compare.exe -metric rmse p1.png tmp.png diff.png 2>&1
    $rmse = ([string] $rmse).split(" ")[1]
    $rmse = $rmse.replace("(","")
    $rmse = [double] $rmse.replace(")","")

    # find rotation angle where RMSE is minimal
    if ($rmse -lt $min_rmse) {
        $min_rmse = $rmse
        $degrees_rotated = $i
    }
}

Write-Host "two images are most similar when second image is rotated by $degrees_rotated deg (rmse is $min_rmse)"
Write-Host "Press any key to exit ..." 
$host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

Hope that helps.

p.s.
According to wiki RMSE between two vectors can be calculated in two different ways. I don't know which one is implemented in ImageMagick as

```
compare.exe -metric rmse
```

command, but for sure this can be determined by asking IM developers or by trial-and-error method.